# How to cancel pending retries on Polly's async WaitAndRetryPolicy

Tags: polly

I‘m using polly for a simple retry n-times szenario on a HTTP POST-request. It should handle any exception and retry to post my payload to the api-endpoint for n-times. Therefore I used a WaitAndRetryPolicy wraping a TimoutPolicy with a pessimistic strategy for a timeout per try. Both as async policies.

When the retry-case is taking place **every** retry-attempt, which was made, is posted to the endpoint after connection is re-esteblished.

The method which wraps the two policies up:

```cs
    public static PolicyWrap WaitAndRetryNTimesWithTimeoutPerTry(int n, TimeSpan sleepDuration, TimeSpan retryTimeout)
    {
        var waitAndRetryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetryAsync(
        retryCount: n,
            sleepDurationProvider: attempt => sleepDuration,
            onRetry: (exception, waitDuration, ctx) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"[Polly.OnRetry due '{exception.Message}'; waiting for {waitDuration.TotalMilliseconds} ms before retrying.");
            }
        );

        var timeoutPerTryPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(
            retryTimeout, TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic);

        return waitAndRetryPolicy.WrapAsync(timeoutPerTryPolicy);
    }
```

The code which calls the web api:

```cs
    var waitAndRetry5TimesWithShortTimeout = ResiliencePolicyFactory.WaitAndRetryNTimesWithTimeoutPerTry(
        n: 5,
        sleepDuration: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(700),
        retryTimeout: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2300));
        }

    try
    {
        await waitAndRetry5TimesWithShortTimeout.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(async token =>
        {
            if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content, cancellationToken);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"[{nameof(CheckinService)}] ===>> Now Checked in!");
                }
            }
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("NoCheckInPossible", ex);
    }
```

When the code hits the retry case and succeed after several retries, every retry-attempt made, is posted to endpoint, eventough I’m passing the cancellation token to ExecuteAsync-Task and the HttpClient.

In my understanding the first successfull request should cancel all pending retries. Can anybody point out, what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Within `ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(...)`, use the token Polly will pass in when executing the delegate (`token` in your case), in order for the timeout to work. In the posted code, that delegate uses your own variable `cancellationToken` (which I can't see if anything is cancelling; certainly the timeout won't). If this fixes it for you, I can write it up as a proper answer.

Comment: Additionally: `TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic` is designed for cases where the executed delegate does not honour cancellation tokens. `HttpClient` does honour those tokens, so you should be able to use the simpler [`TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#optimistic-timeout).

Comment: [`TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic` only _walks away from_ timed-out executions](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#pessimistic-timeout), which is probably why you are seeing earlier tries continue to completion - you haven't actually cancelled them (poss due to using the wrong cancellation token; see first comment), so they will also complete if the underlying connection is reestablished before `HttpClient`'s own timeout (default: 30 seconds).

Answer (score 5):

The issue looks to be that this line:

```
response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content, cancellationToken);
```

is using a variable called `cancellationToken`, not the variable `token` which Polly passes in to the executed delegate at `async token =>`.

Using the below should fix it:

```
response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content, token);
```

### Explanation

Polly timeout policies [combine a timing-out `CancellationToken` into any cancellationToken the caller passes into the execution](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/4db50346299f62c2373ceba99d2522a8171c9e27/src/Polly/Timeout/AsyncTimeoutEngine.cs#L22-L27), but for that timing-out token to have any effect, within the executed delegate you must use the token Polly supplies to the execution (the variable `token` in this case).

(From the code posted in the question, we can't see that anything signals cancellation of `cancellationToken`; if something does, please comment or edit the question to clarify.)

With the code `client.PostAsync(uri, content, cancellationToken)`, if nothing is cancelling `cancellationToken`, then each POST never gets cancelled, which likely explains why you are seeing multiple POSTs run to completion.

### Demonstration

I made a runnable [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) close to your posted code, to demonstrate.

```
public static Random rand = new Random();

public static async Task Main()
{

    var waitAndRetry5TimesWithShortTimeout = WaitAndRetryNTimesWithTimeoutPerTry(
        n: 5,
        sleepDuration: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(70),
        retryTimeout: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(230));

    CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource().Token;

    string response;
    try
    {
        await waitAndRetry5TimesWithShortTimeout.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(async token =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Placing call");
            if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                response = await PretendPostAsync(cancellationToken); // Change 'cancellationToken' to 'token' here, and it will start to work as expected.
                if (response == "success")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Now Checked in!");
                }
            }
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("NoCheckInPossible", ex);
    }

}

public static async Task<string> PretendPostAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    if (rand.Next(4) != 0)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), token);
    }

    return "success";
}

public static AsyncPolicyWrap WaitAndRetryNTimesWithTimeoutPerTry(int n, TimeSpan sleepDuration, TimeSpan retryTimeout)
{
    var waitAndRetryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetryAsync(
    retryCount: n,
        sleepDurationProvider: attempt => sleepDuration,
        onRetry: (exception, waitDuration, ctx) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[Polly.OnRetry due '{exception.Message}'; waiting for {waitDuration.TotalMilliseconds} ms before retrying.");
        }
    );

    var timeoutPerTryPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(
        retryTimeout, TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic);

    return waitAndRetryPolicy.WrapAsync(timeoutPerTryPolicy);
}
```

You can [run this in DotNetFiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lSD1pb) and see that it typically gives output like:

```
Placing call
[Polly.OnRetry due 'The delegate executed asynchronously through TimeoutPolicy did not complete within the timeout.'; waiting for 70 ms before retrying.
Placing call
Now Checked in!
[Polly.OnRetry due 'The delegate executed asynchronously through TimeoutPolicy did not complete within the timeout.'; waiting for 70 ms before retrying.
Placing call
Now Checked in!
```

(*The code example randomises to simulate different degrees of failure; you might have to run it a few times to see similar results.*)

Multiple calls clearly get placed (`Placing call`), and multiple run to completion (`Now Checked in!`), because nothing cancels them.

Change the line indicated to use `token`, and it can be seen that even if multiple calls are placed, earlier tries are cancelled, and only one succeeds.

```
Placing call
[Polly.OnRetry due 'The delegate executed asynchronously through TimeoutPolicy did not complete within the timeout.'; waiting for 70 ms before retrying.
Placing call
[Polly.OnRetry due 'The delegate executed asynchronously through TimeoutPolicy did not complete within the timeout.'; waiting for 70 ms before retrying.
Placing call
Now Checked in!
```

### Tidying up

Because `HttpClient.PostAsync(...)` does honor `CancellationToken`s, you can use the slightly more efficient [`TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#optimistic-timeout).